# How to run the VBA example on the Microsoft "AddressOf operator" documentation page

Tags: excel, vba

On the Microsoft Documentation page for `AddressOf operator` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/addressof-operator), there are two blocks of code. However the first block of code gives the expected error `List1` not defined. So, hoe do I make the example code work on Excel VBA?

Example code Block 1:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Module1.FillListWithFonts List1
End Sub
```

Example code Block 2:

```
'Font enumeration types
Public Const LF_FACESIZE = 32
Public Const LF_FULLFACESIZE = 64

Type LOGFONT
        lfHeight As Long
        lfWidth As Long
        lfEscapement As Long
        lfOrientation As Long
        lfWeight As Long
        lfItalic As Byte
        lfUnderline As Byte
        lfStrikeOut As Byte
        lfCharSet As Byte
        lfOutPrecision As Byte
        lfClipPrecision As Byte
        lfQuality As Byte
        lfPitchAndFamily As Byte
        lfFaceName(LF_FACESIZE) As Byte
End Type

Type NEWTEXTMETRIC
        tmHeight As Long
        tmAscent As Long
        tmDescent As Long
        tmInternalLeading As Long
        tmExternalLeading As Long
        tmAveCharWidth As Long
        tmMaxCharWidth As Long
        tmWeight As Long
        tmOverhang As Long
        tmDigitizedAspectX As Long
        tmDigitizedAspectY As Long
        tmFirstChar As Byte
        tmLastChar As Byte
        tmDefaultChar As Byte
        tmBreakChar As Byte
        tmItalic As Byte
        tmUnderlined As Byte
        tmStruckOut As Byte
        tmPitchAndFamily As Byte
        tmCharSet As Byte
        ntmFlags As Long
        ntmSizeEM As Long
        ntmCellHeight As Long
        ntmAveWidth As Long
End Type

' ntmFlags field flags
Public Const NTM_REGULAR = &H40&
Public Const NTM_BOLD = &H20&
Public Const NTM_ITALIC = &H1&

'  tmPitchAndFamily flags
Public Const TMPF_FIXED_PITCH = &H1
Public Const TMPF_VECTOR = &H2
Public Const TMPF_DEVICE = &H8
Public Const TMPF_TRUETYPE = &H4

Public Const ELF_VERSION = 0
Public Const ELF_CULTURE_LATIN = 0

'  EnumFonts Masks
Public Const RASTER_FONTTYPE = &H1
Public Const DEVICE_FONTTYPE = &H2
Public Const TRUETYPE_FONTTYPE = &H4

Declare Function EnumFontFamilies Lib "gdi32" Alias _
     "EnumFontFamiliesA" _
     (ByVal hDC As Long, ByVal lpszFamily As String, _ 
     ByVal lpEnumFontFamProc As Long, LParam As Any) As Long
Declare Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Declare Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, _
     ByVal hDC As Long) As Long

Function EnumFontFamProc(lpNLF As LOGFONT, lpNTM As NEWTEXTMETRIC, _ 
     ByVal FontType As Long, LParam As ListBox) As Long
Dim FaceName As String
Dim FullName As String
    FaceName = StrConv(lpNLF.lfFaceName, vbUnicode)
    LParam.AddItem Left$(FaceName, InStr(FaceName, vbNullChar) - 1)
    EnumFontFamProc = 1
End Function

Sub FillListWithFonts(LB As ListBox)
Dim hDC As Long
    LB.Clear
    hDC = GetDC(LB.hWnd)
    EnumFontFamilies hDC, vbNullString, AddressOf EnumFontFamProc, LB
    ReleaseDC LB.hWnd, hDC
End Sub
```

Another thing is about the information on the same page that the `AddressOf` should be used in conjugation with the `On Error Resume Next`, however this isn't present on the given example. I would like to know how to use it too.

Thanks

Comment: Block 1 needs to be in a new Userform to which you have added a ListBox control that you name "List1".

Comment: The link says "To run this example, create a form with a list box on it." -- did you try that?

Comment: That code is clearly lifted straight from a VB6 article (`Form_Load` is a VB6 event) and won't run in VBA since neither of the types of Listbox available in Excel have an `hWnd` property.

Comment: @Rory Although, somewhat oddly, the link is to a page which purports to be Office VBA documentation. Even Microsoft in its own documentation sometimes has a hard time keeping all of its dialects of Visual Basic straight.

Comment: Callback functions trough `AddressOf` operator applies to VBA too not only VB.net. Yes Microsoft is extremely cryptic in their Documentation!